# Child Process with Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor

I use Child-Process with NodeJS to call my .exe , but now I'm using meteor.
How could I call my .exe from Meteor?

This is the code used in Node

```
    const exec = require('child_process').exec;
    exec('"C:\\Users\\obarrera\\Desktop\\desktop.exe" omar_barrera', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(stdout);
    });
```

Comment: and what doesn't work?

Comment: I guess the question should be, how can I pass stdout,stderr to client ?

Answer (score 5):

You can do something very similar in Meteor. I would suggest moving the exe file into your Meteor project, though. If you move your `desktop.exe` file to the `private` directory within your project, you can do the following:

```
import childProcess from 'child_process';
childProcess.exec('assets/app/desktop.exe omar_barrera', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

Of course, make sure you use `npm install --save child_process` in your Meteor project first.

Comment: how's putting a file into private folder, gave aceedd to meteor via assets/app directory? Btw it worked for me, I was looking for this for aw hile